# Code Scanner Portal show error in browser console

Tags: security-review, developer, security-scanner

I try do security scanner for our code. I use this "Force.com Code Scanner Portal" website to do it. This is the website link: https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner

After I input username like follow image.

[image]

It don't a robot check like normal, and when I click Scan Organization Button something happen. I check Browser Console and found errors. Please check follow image.

[image]

I want to know is this an issue in this web-site or my browser settings problem? Do you have any idea how to resolve this.

My Browser is Chrome. Version 90.0.4430.85

Best wishes,
Lee

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins that try to suppress reCaptcha usage?

Comment: @PhilW, thanks for you idea. I can success run scan now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in this web site and it already been fixed.